# MongoDB - Is it possible to group by date and reorder into an array?

Tags: mongodb

I've got a nodejs backend running connected to mongodb. My documents look like:

```
{
  _id: ObjectID
  date: "2020-05-05T09:01:55.868+00:00"
  keyA: valueA
  keyB: valueB
},
{
  _id: ObjectID
  date: "2020-05-05T09:01:55.868+00:00"
  keyA: valueC
  keyB: valueD
},
{
  _id: ObjectID
  date: "2020-05-05T09:02:56.868+00:00"
  keyA: valueE
  keyB: valueF
}
```

Now I would like to group all my documents by date but without losing the extra values. My result should look like:

```
{
  date: "2020-05-05T09:01:55.000+00:00"
  items: [
    {
      keyA: valueA
      keyB: valueB
    },
    {
      keyA: valueC
      keyB: valueD
    }
  ]
},
{
  date: "2020-05-05T09:02:56.000+00:00"
  items: [
    {
      keyA: valueE
      keyB: valueF
    }
  ]
}
```

What's the best way to achieve something like that? I guess I could just query all and write some plain js, but for the sake of speed and simplicity I would like to combine all in a mongodb query. I found many post about the aggregate $group function but all they use it for is counting how many, in my case items, are found. As you might have noticed I not only want to group by the exact same date but by timeframes, in my case 1s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
db.helloworld.aggregate ([
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$date",
                items: { $push: { keyA: "$keyA", keyB: "$keyB" } }
            }
        }
    ])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was looking for.